# get text between two pair of tags in the same line

Tags: grep

I've two pairs of tags in the same line and I would like to get the string between each of them separately.

```
echo 'the <key>text</key> between the two "<key>pairs</key>" and so on' | grep -o '<key>.*</key>'
```

returns the text between the two pairs but I'm aiming for getting 'text' and 'pairs' returned only

thanks for the indications

```
gawk -v RS='</?key>' 'RT=="</key>"'
```

does the job

Comment: You can't accomplish this with `grep` (a tool for finding whole lines in files).  Use `awk` or `perl`, etc. instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ echo 'the <key>text</key> between the two "<key>pairs</key>" and so on' |
gawk -v RS='</?key>' '!(NR%2)'
text
pairs
```